# VSCode adds control and script code to first line of output

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I am accessing a cluster using visual studio code and have noticed that something has been added to the start of my first line of some files. It looks like some kind of non-printing control and hex code string, along with my bash command. I have looked around the stack and have not found a clear answer other than turning off plugins.

I do not believe it is an issue with any plugins on VSCode. I have disabled all plugins that aren't necessary and restarted VSCode to access the cluster and run my example here. All commands are run through through the terminal on VSCode. I don't touch the files with the VSCodes text editor, I am just looking at the markdown file I use to take notes about my pipeline.

```
$ code --list-extensions 
Extensions installed on SSH: ###.###.##.##:
```

So, I am unsure if it is VSCode or *my* code, I am checking here to make sure that it is not something in my code. I am using a combination of awk and bash for loops in my scripts.

**Here is the server information**

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

**Here is my laptops OS information**

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-79-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

The goal of my pipeline is to change the name of multi-fasta headers for downstream work. I need to keep a record of what has been changed. There are previous steps in my pipeline, but until now I was just checking the first line manually (poor practice).

Example data:
Here is my input file `4probe-reduction/Vasil.subset.fasta`:

```
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_1 |desiger:Vasilikopoulos-et-al_2021_AHE
CTCATCCTAATTCTGCGAGCGCTGCACGTTAACACGGAGAGGACCAAGGTGGTACTGAAACCGGACAAGACGACCGTCACAGAACCTCACCACATTTGGCCGACGCTAGCCGATGACGAC
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_2 |desiger:Vasilikopoulos-et-al_2021_AHE
TTGATCTTAATTTTACGTGCTCTCCATGTAAATACTGAACGAACGAAAGTGGTATTGAAACCTGACAAAACCACAATTACAGAACCGCATCACATCTGGCCTACGTTGTCAGATGATGAG
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_3 |desiger:Vasilikopoulos-et-al_2021_AHE
TTGATTCTAATTCTACGTGCCCTTCACGTGAACACGGAACGCACCAAGGTTGTATTGAAGCCAGATAAAACAACAATAACGGAGCCTCACCATATCTGGCCGACTCTCTCTGACGATGAA
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_4 |desiger:Vasilikopoulos-et-al_2021_AHE
TTAATTTTAATTCTCCGAGCCTTGCACGTTAATACAGAACGTACGAAAGTTGTTCTCAAACCTGACAAAACAACAATAACTGAACCGCATCACATCTGGCCTACTCTCTCCGATGATGAG
```

and the directory structure

```
.
├── 4probe-reduction
│   └── Vasil.subset.fasta
└── 5join-probes
```

---

This is the start of my code

```
# append name to end of fasta header
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";-F" |"} (NR>1) {print ">" $1 " " $2",original-probe-ID:"$1 "\n" $3}' 4probe-reduction/Vasil.subset.fasta > 5join-probes/Vasil.subset.tmp
# start making reference list
grep ">" 5join-probes/Vasil.subset.tmp | cut -d"|" -f1 | tr -d ">" > 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.list
```

This is slow with a large file but it does what I need it too, create a TSV with information of what is being changed. This is where the problem starts.

```
for i in $(cat 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.list); do
LOCI=$(echo $i | cut -d _ -f 1,2,3);
echo -e $i "\t" $LOCI;
done > 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list
```

For SOME reason this previous step introduces information from my for loop in the file. If I `head` the file, it looks fine.

```
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_1          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_2          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_3          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_4          TC010565-PA_3_21
```

However, to show the real issue I have to use cat -v, nano, or vim. There is clearly a non-printing string *and* part of my for loop for some reason.

```
^[]633;C^G^[]633;E;for i in $(cat 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.list);dd7e81cf-f180-4cfa-bb78-96375b809d55^GTC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_1          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_2          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_3          TC010565-PA_3_21
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_4          TC010565-PA_3_21
```

This awk step needs to be corrected because its not counting properly, and I am not sure if the issue I am having comes from the strange string introduced in my file

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=2000000;probe[0]=""};
{if(!($2 in probe)) {probe[$2]=count++};
print $0, "\t", "uce-"count}' 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list > 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list2
```

again, with nano the problem persists (as expected).

```
^[]633;C^G^[]633;E;for i in $(cat 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.list);dd7e81cf-f180-4cfa-bb78-96375b809d55^GTC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_1          TC010565-PA_3_21        uce-2000001
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_2          TC010565-PA_3_21        uce-2000002
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_3          TC010565-PA_3_21        uce-2000002
TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_4          TC010565-PA_3_21        uce-2000002
```

This next step is adding necessary formating for a software I will be using

```
awk '$3 != save { counter = 1; save = $3 }
{ print $0, "\t", "_p" counter++ }' 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list2 > 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list3
awk '{print ">" $1, "\t", ">" $3 $4}' 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list3 > 5join-probes/Vasil.renamed-probe.list
```

However, now if I try to head the file it gives me an empty output, but I can see the file using nano.

```
>^[]633;C^G^[]633;E;for          >in$(cat
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_2         >uce-2000002_p1
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_3         >uce-2000002_p2
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_4         >uce-2000002_p3
>TC010565-PA_3_21_13_1_5         >uce-2000002_p4
```

---

## Edit

The issues only occur *in* VSCode. I've made changes suggested by @rioV8 in the for loop, and its an immediate fix to my issue:

```
touch 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list
for i in $(cat 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.list); do
LOCI=$(echo $i | cut -d _ -f 1,2,3);
echo -e $i "\t" $LOCI >> 5join-probes/Vasil-rename.tmp.list; 
done
```

But this indicates VSCode is doing things in my command line while SSH'd into the server. The only plugins activated are for SSH'ing into the server.

Comment: what if don't try to pipe the output of `for` to a file but append to a file the `echo` line, remove the temp file before the for loop, everything **before** `do` is show in the output file

Comment: if you run the scripts without VSC do you see the same behavior? Use an ssh connection outside VSC

Comment: @rioV8 Using my terminal to SSH into the server I don't see the same behavior

Comment: This is why I used the visual-studio-code tag. I should have used that information in the original post. Isn't it appropriate to use this tag if the problem only occurs in visual studio code?

Comment: you have a remote terminal **in VSC** to the server, you start the scripts on the command line and you get these extra texts? Why would tunneling the stdin and stdout of the terminal to the local machine have influence on the scripts?

Comment: @rioV8 
I made the changes to the for loop, creating a list to append the output of my for loop solves the immediate issue. But, it still indicates something VSCode is doing to my scripts I don't want it doing.

Comment: @rioV8
I am connecting to the server using VSCode.

Comment: then create an issue at the Remote SSH extension